# How to see in which date range does a date lie in and assign values accordingly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dfs:

`threshold`

```
    id  meter_point_id  valid_from  valid_until     max_power_contractual
0   3   61  1969-12-31 23:00:00 2019-11-06 23:00:00 0
1   79  61  2019-11-07 00:00:00 2020-07-13 00:00:00 10
```

`data`

```
    id  ds  time_series_id  y
0   12858   2019-03-21 14:30:00 12858   49.25
1   12858   2019-03-21 14:15:00 12858   52.5
2   12858   2019-03-21 17:15:00 12858   49.25
3   12858   2019-03-21 13:45:00 12858   49.0
4   12858   2019-03-21 13:30:00 12858   51.75
5   22231   2019-11-11 12:00:00 22231   10.5
6   22231   2019-11-11 11:45:00 22231   10.0
7   22231   2019-11-12 09:45:00 22231   10.0
8   22231   2019-11-14 21:45:00 22231   9.5
```

I want to check every date in `ds` column in the `data` df against the `valid_from` and `valid_until` dates in the `threshold` columns. If a date in the `ds` lies in the date range `1969-12-31 23:00:00`-`2019-11-06 23:00:00`, I want to obtain the `max_power_contractual` value from the `threshold` df and create it as a new column in the `data` df.

**Expected output**

```
    id  ds  time_series_id  y max_power_contractual
0   12858   2019-03-21 14:30:00 12858   49.25 0
1   12858   2019-03-21 14:15:00 12858   52.5  0
2   12858   2019-03-21 17:15:00 12858   49.25 0
3   12858   2019-03-21 13:45:00 12858   49.0  0
4   12858   2019-03-21 13:30:00 12858   51.75 0
5   22231   2019-11-11 12:00:00 22231   10.5  10
6   22231   2019-11-11 11:45:00 22231   10.0  10
7   22231   2019-11-12 09:45:00 22231   10.0  10
8   22231   2019-11-14 21:45:00 22231   9.5   10
```

In the first 5 rows of the `data` df, the `ds` values match with the date range in the first row of `threshold` df, so since the `max_power_contractual` for that date range is 0, I want that value in the `data` df. Similarly, the last rows 4 of the `data` df, the `ds` values match with the date range in the second row of `threshold` df, so since the `max_power_contractual` for that date range is 10, I want that value in the `data` df.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? Please get rid of useless columns...

Comment: Done. Please check the updated question @RiccardoBucco

Comment: Hey thanks for your update, I'm going to have a look at the question and help you! Just one last thing: can you provide the code to build the dataframes? Like `df = pd.Dataframe(...)` etc. It's important to know how you built the data objects. Also it speeds up our work ;)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco I am reading the data from a database, so I don't have the `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` part of the code

Comment: @reinhardt Can the interval `valid_from` and `valid_until` dates overlap in multiple rows in threshold dataframe? f**or example** if first row contains `1969-12-31 2019-11-06`, can it be possible for another row to contain **e.g**  `2017-11-06  2021-12-06` or `1967-12-11 1982-02-11`?

Comment: Hey @ShubhamSharma, no the time intervals will never overlap.  I also updated the `threshold` table. There was a tiny mistake

Comment: @reinhardt Are all the columns already in pandas datetime column format?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma No, they have to be converted. I think `pd.to_datetime()` does it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert the date like columns in both the dataframes to pandas `datetime` series using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
threshold['valid_from']  = pd.to_datetime(threshold['valid_from'])
threshold['valid_until'] = pd.to_datetime(threshold['valid_until'])
data['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(data['ds'])
```

**Then use:**

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(threshold['valid_from'], threshold['valid_until'])
mapping = threshold.set_index(idx)['max_power_contractual']
data['max_power_contractual'] = data['ds'].map(mapping)
```

**Details:**

STEP A: Create a [`pd.IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) from the `valid_from` and `valid_until` columns, this IntervalIndex will be used in `STEP C` for mapping the column `ds`:

```
# print(idx)
IntervalIndex([(1969-12-31 23:00:00, 2019-11-06 23:00:00], (2019-11-07, 2020-07-13]],
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[datetime64[ns]]')
```

STEP B: Use [`.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to set the index of `max_power_contractual` series to this interval index `idx`:

```
# print(mapping)
(1969-12-31 23:00:00, 2019-11-06 23:00:00]     0
(2019-11-07, 2020-07-13]                      10
Name: max_power_contractual, dtype: int64
```

STEP C: Finally use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the column `ds` with this `mapping` series and assign it to the new column in `data`.

```
# print(data)

      id                  ds  time_series_id      y  max_power_contractual
0  12858 2019-03-21 14:30:00           12858  49.25                      0
1  12858 2019-03-21 14:15:00           12858  52.50                      0
2  12858 2019-03-21 17:15:00           12858  49.25                      0
3  12858 2019-03-21 13:45:00           12858  49.00                      0
4  12858 2019-03-21 13:30:00           12858  51.75                      0
5  22231 2019-11-11 12:00:00           22231  10.50                     10
6  22231 2019-11-11 11:45:00           22231  10.00                     10
7  22231 2019-11-12 09:45:00           22231  10.00                     10
8  22231 2019-11-14 21:45:00           22231   9.50                     10
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. It works. I just have one question: Running this takes quite some time. Is there any way to improve the speed? I tried mentioning the `format` parameter too in `pd.to_datetime()`, but still no difference. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the shape of your dateframe?

Comment: It is (21600, 16)

Comment: Considering the size, this will probably take some time, but again other option we have is `merge`, but i dont think that will be going to take any less time than this.

Comment: Could you also give the solution with `merge`? I would like to check it too

Comment: @reinhardt Trust me, `merge` will not improve the performance that much.. Because in that case we have to look for every possible combination.